# Will the Office 365 Unified API replace other MS APIs like Exchange Online?

Tags: api, rest, azure, office365

We are investigating solutions to integrate an Outlook user's calendar with our app and have looked into two Office 365 APIs - Unified (preview) and Exchange Online. So far, I've had issues trying to sign up for Exchange Online (either getting an Azure AD user to get Exchange Online, or to get an Exchange Online user to get Azure...I can't get both!) and it looks like Unified will be the standard API to use in the future. We've got things setup to use Unified, but are running into some server errors that do not seem like due to our configuration/code. ([Oauth into Office 365 Unified (preview) - server error - non-retryable error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927032/oauth-into-office-365-unified-preview-server-error-non-retryable-error-has))

To move forward with our project, is it recommended to continue researching Unified? Will Exchange Online eventually be deprecated and replaced by Unified?

Answer (score 0):

Victor, there are no plans to deprecate the Outlook API's endpoint. The Unified API exists to simplify things if you are using multiple endpoints (SharePoint Online, Graph, etc). If calendaring is your main goal, the Outlook API is appropriate.

Also bear in mind that Unified is still in Preview and may have some issues.